# PHP: How to sort the characters should be in the order of first occurrence

Tags: php

I have string to be separated between vowels and consonants make them lower and ignore white space. sort by character according to the order they came out.

example string :

```
Sample Case
```

my output is :

```
vowels     : aeae  
consonants : smplcs
```

my expectation output is :

```
vowels     : aaee  
consonants : ssmplc
```

```
function sortCharacter($chars){
    $chars  = strtolower($chars);
    $chars  = str_replace(' ','',$chars);
    $chars2 = str_split($chars);

    $vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    $v=[];
    $c=[];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($chars2) ; $i++) {
        if (in_array($chars2[$i], $vowels)) {
            array_push($v, $chars2[$i]);
        }else{
            array_push($c, $chars2[$i]);
        }

    }


    
    echo "Vowel Character : <br>" ;     
    echo implode("", $v)."<br>";  
    echo "Consonant Character : <br>" ;     
    echo implode("", $c);
    
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: just update my code

Comment: What do you mean by _"according to the order they came out"_ if `smplcs` is wrong?

Comment: mean if character "s" come out, get all "s" character in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = 'Sample Case';

$vowels = '';
foreach (array_count_values(str_split(preg_replace('/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz ]/', '', strtolower($text)))) as $k => $v) {
  $vowels .= str_repeat($k, $v);
}

$consonants = '';
foreach (array_count_values(str_split(preg_replace('/[aeiou ]/', '', strtolower($text)))) as $k => $v) {
  $consonants .= str_repeat($k, $v);
}

print_r($vowels);
echo "\n";
print_r($consonants);
```

Output:

```
aaee
ssmplc
```

Comment: I don't understand why the vowels start with `ss...`. Ah, the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71177008/php-how-to-sort-the-characters-according-to-the-order-they-came-out#comment125817219_71177008 explains it.

Comment: The OP states the characters should be in the order of first occurrence in the string (at least that is how I understood the example output provided in the OP).